# How to classify Eurostyle

Tags: terminology, typefaces, style-identification

How do you classify Eurostile and similar boxy and wide typefaces? Geometric Sans Serifs come up as a suggestion, and I understand why, but I hope that there is another sub-classification for it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for here, but Eurostyle is generally viewed as a "display font", for use in headlines or signs, i.e. for improved legibility at large sizes, as opposed to copy/body text at small sizes where it would be more difficult to read. Is this the kind of thing you are looking for?  If so, I could add it as an answer.

Comment: Hmm, well I’m looking for a type classification that describes its form. Display seems too broad because it includes all type of shapes, even if I understand what you are saying. Someone suggested Square sans serif which might be clooser.

Answer (score 2):

[Eurostile](https://www.fontshop.com/families/urw-eurostile) is a Geometric Sans-Serif designed by [Aldo Novarese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldo_Novarese). I believe you can sub-classify however you want, but that is just inventing new names - is it really necessary? Should we have fonts classified by their corner radiuses for example?

On [Fonts.com](https://www.fonts.com/browse) search filters you can only see 6 classes:

- Sans
- Serif
- Script
- Display
- Symbol
- Monospaced

I believe these are more than enough to describe most typefaces correctly.